# echo response php +json encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

My problem is that in the first code below it doesn't display the data on browser, just shows a black page. There are no errors in the logs.

Another thing this displays the data using var_dump or print_r but then it doesn't encode in the right json format.

Is there a way of echoing the response? On the second code I follow exactly the same procedure as the first and it shows me the data I want without var_dum or print_r.

### First code

```
<?php
/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/conectaDB.php';
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
// check for post data
// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("select cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, (select sum(quantidade) from lin_doc where id_cab_doc = cd.id) as qtd from cab_doc cd where cd.id_tipo_doc = 1") or die(mysql_error());
// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["cab_doc"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        var_dump($row);
        // temp user array
        $linha                = array();
        $linha["id"]          = $row["id"];
        $linha["dt_ini_camp"] = $row["dt_ini_camp"];
        $linha["dt_fim_camp"] = $row["dt_fim_camp"];
        $linha["descricao"]   = $row["descricao"];
        $linha["qtd"]         = $row["qtd"];
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["cab_doc"], $linha);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";
    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The output of this code is a blank page.

### Second code

The below works fine and displays the data:

```
<?php
/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/conectaDB.php';
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
// check for post data
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // get all products from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, id_estab, dt, hr, quantidade FROM lin_doc WHERE id_cab_doc = $id") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response["lin_doc"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            //var_dump($row);
            // temp user array
            $linha               = array();
            $linha["id"]         = $row["id"];
            $linha["id_estab"]   = $row["id_estab"];
            $linha["dt"]         = $row["dt"];
            $linha["hr"]         = $row["hr"];
            $linha["quantidade"] = $row["quantidade"];
            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["lin_doc"], $linha);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no products found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No products found";
        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Output of second code:

> {"lin_doc":[{"id":"66","id_estab":"12","dt":"2013-03-26","hr":"16:30:00","quantidade":"373.000"},{"id":"148","id_estab":"16","dt":"2013-07-08","hr":"20:45:00","quantidade":"119.000"},{"id":"260","id_estab":"14","dt":"2012-09-20","hr":"20:00:00","quantidade":"324.000"},{"id":"275","id_estab":"33","dt":"2012-07-23","hr":"22:00:00","quantidade":"489.000"},{"id":"306","id_estab":"25","dt":"2012-07-27","hr":"20:45:00","quantidade":"338.000"},{"id":"468","id_estab":"15","dt":"2013-04-23","hr":"20:45:00","quantidade":"263.000"},{"id":"546","id_estab":"18","dt":"2013-05-22","hr":"11:15:00","quantidade":"87.000"},{"id":"578","id_estab":"11","dt":"2013-03-06","hr":"13:30:00","quantidade":"30.000"},{"id":"601","id_estab":"07","dt":"2013-02-23","hr":"20:00:00","quantidade":"87.000"},{"id":"617","id_estab":"14","dt":"2012-11-23","hr":"20:45:00","quantidade":"234.000"},{"id":"651","id_estab":"03","dt":"2013-05-12","hr":"20:45:00","quantidade":"311.000"},{"id":"752","id_estab":"06","dt":"2013-01-13","hr":"13:30:00","quantidade":"219.000"},{"id":"803","id_estab":"22","dt":"2013-02-23","hr":"16:30:00","quantidade":"396.000"},{"id":"819","id_estab":"06","dt":"2012-10-21","hr":"18:15:00","quantidade":"333.000"},{"id":"850","id_estab":"03","dt":"2013-01-19","hr":"14:30:00","quantidade":"265.000"},{"id":"899","id_estab":"22","dt":"2013-06-15","hr":"13:00:00","quantidade":"453.000"},{"id":"993","id_estab":"10","dt":"2013-02-03","hr":"19:30:00","quantidade":"441.000"}],
>   "success":1}

Comment: In the first example you are showing you connect with the database through a class called `DB_CONNECT` but continue on with `mysql_`-functions, this is probably wrong.

Comment: no thats is to connect to my database.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt paying attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connect: mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);

try:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('your_db', $link);
```

or encode your array:

```
foreach( $row as $value ) {
    $value = utf8_encode( $value );
}
```

I'm not sure if your query is ok in this point:

```
"as qtd from cab_doc cd where cd.id_tipo_doc = 1"
                    ^^^^
```

Comment: men i fuking love y since 3 days, ive posted the same question over and over again and no one really helped. y are the best ;)